# eMail link in betas contains + instead of spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

Maybe you should escape the spaces?

```
mailto:?subject=Stack+Exchange+Q%26A+site+public+beta%3a+Gaming&body=Hi!%0d%0a%0d%0aI'm+supporting+a+proposal+to+create+a+new+Q%26A+website+for+passionate+videogamers+on+all+platforms.%0d%0a%0d%0aIt's+built+on+the+same+software+as+stackoverflow.com%2c+a+hugely+popular+site+where+over+seven+million+programmers+help+each+other+with+difficult+programming+problems.+On+Stack+Overflow+the+audience+votes+for+the+best+answer%2c+so+the+answer+you+want+is+usually+right+at+the+top%2c+not+on+page+five.%0d%0a%0d%0aI'm+hoping+that+a+site+for+passionate+videogamers+on+all+platforms+would+have+the+same+kind+of+network+effect+and+turn+into+an+amazing+resource.%0d%0a%0d%0aThe+public+beta+is+going+on+here%2c+if+you're+interested+in+participating%3a%0d%0a%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fgaming.stackexchange.com%0d%0a%0d%0aThanks!
```

Comment: @David thanks, it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uri encoding, a *+* is an acceptable and recommended replacement for space. It is definitely more desired than the less readable *%20*. When you search with google, spaces in the search terms are replaced with *+*.  The same applies to all form fields.

Answer (score 0):

How is this wrong? The resulting launch of mail client processes it correctly.

Comment: Thunderbird 3.0.4 (win) starts up with the pluses and no spaces. But ok, then it is a T-bird issue